# Flip direction of popup when page end reaches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bubble which comes up when I click on an icon just below it. But if the icon appears at the end of the page, then when I click it, the popup goes below the page. I want to avoid this by detecting the end of the page and this case making the popup come on top.

I tried using `$(window).height()` to detect the height and then check the current position of the popup and change it accordingly if its at window end. But is there a better approach to it?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem and solved it with scrollIntoView function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.getElementById('pop-up').scrollHeight
```